# How to navigate multiple folders from app.js

Tags: react-native

I have a file structure like below

```
screens
 ..components
    Avatar.js
 ..Contacts
   ManageContacts.js
 ..Login
   Signup.js
```

I am new to React Native application development and I have tried several ways to redirect files from App.js but nothing helped me.

```
App.js
1.const ManageContacts = React.lazy(() => import('../screens/Contacts/ManageContacts'));
2.const ManageContacts = React.lazy(() => import('../../screens/Contacts/ManageContacts'));
3.const ManageContacts = React.lazy(() => import('../../ManageContacts'));
4.const ManageContacts = React.lazy(() => import('./screens/Contacts/ManageContacts'));
```

Inside my App.js file I have tried to import the files like above 4 ways. But always I am getting error and am unable to resolve.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean by redirecting files?

Comment: I want to use Managecontacts.js in App,js. so how wii i call managecontacts file

Comment: Does you mean importing functions from `Managecontacts.js` in `App.js` ?

Comment: @AdarshRaj i want to import manageContacts to mention inside stackNavigator

Comment: then why are you making it so complicated just `import` as you `import` other modules. i.e
`import manageContacts from './screens/Contacts/ManageContacts';`

Comment: I tried but i am getting error like unable to resolve module ../screens/Contacts/MangeContacts

Comment: then may be directory would be wrong can you show all directory list? or `App.js` is exactly outside of screens?

Comment: yes App.js is outside of screens folder

Comment: `../screens/Contacts/MangeContacts` can you try to remove first dot from this? and then try

Comment: thank you so much i have tried your suggestion its working

Comment: Actually you went one directory back by `../` i.e outside of your project folder.

Comment: @AdarshRaj now i understood how to import files from different directories